# rails find similar products other customers ordered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a simple app where users can view products and preorder them so they have one in stock when they get released.

`A Product has many preorders, and many users through preorders.`

`A User has many preorders, and many products through preorders.`

I would like to show other products that other people have preordered to when you view a product. I've tried many combinations of joins where etc, but I'm not sure how to wrap my head around it.

When viewing a product I need to find all the users who have preordered this specific product. Then I need to list all of the products those users have preorders for, and ideally they would be ordered by the number of times they have been preordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but I'll try.

```
product.users # Gives you the users with preorders for that specific product.
```

For all products those users have preordered:

```
user.preorders # will give you all preorders for a given user.
```

## Update

You have a product, you want to get more products according users who have preordered product, to make a list of tuples (product, preorders_count).

```
products = product.users.products # products not defined yet, see below
```

### User model

```
def self.products
  # [[pid1, pid2], [pid1], [pid2]]
  # includes to reduce the number of queries
  product_ids = includes(:products).all.map(&:product_ids)
  # [pid1, pid2]
  product_ids.flatten!.uniq!
  # return a relation ,so you can call product.users.products.where...
  Product.where id: product_ids
end
```

Then you can use:

```
products.each do |product|
  product.preorders.size
end
```

### Suggestion

You can use a cached counter for preorders in products table

```
rails g migration add_preorders_count_to_products preorders_count:integer
# verify your migration
rake db:migrate
```

and in preorder model:

```
belongs_to :product, counter_cache: true
```

I have not tested this all, can you?

Comment: Wow. that's alot easier than I was anticipating. Didn't think of jumping through the :through associations directly, I kept trying to do things like Products.join(:preorders).where(user_id: user.id) etc...

So now I need to take that long list of results, count the duplicates(to order by popularity), remove the duplicates, and list them. A nested `each.do` in the view doesn't seem to fit. Is there a better way?

Comment: Perfect. I had to remove .flatten!.uniq! though, they provided 0 results when only a single user had a preorder when it should show that users other preorders. Also needed a `product.users.products.where("id not in (?), product.id)` to exclude the current product from the list.

Comment: nice!, you can extract last part to a scope for that to make it more readable, in products model: `scope :not, ->(products){...}`

Comment: Trying to add the scope :exclude_current on the product model, but I'm not sure of a way to reference self.id within the model? 

`scope :exclude_current, -> { where('id not in (?)', self.id )}` starts throwing many errors

Comment: scope creates a class function so `current` does not make sense there, anyway I think you can do it more or less like this: `scope :not, ->{ |product| where('id not in (?)', product.id)}` you will use `products.not(product)`

Comment: there we go. Though |product| thew 'unexpected |' error, it looks like it's `scope :exclude, ->(product) { where('id not in (?)', product.id )}`   Thanks! Wish I could give more rate ups!

Comment: good, I did not know very good the lambda syntax, but now I learnt how is it.